# Level required to increase spell damage

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

An interesting question came up last night.

Player X is 4th lvl cleric and 1st lvl monk.

Produce flame can be thrown for d8 of damage. Its damage increases to 2d8 at 5th lvl.

Does this mean at 5th lvl overall or at 5th lvl of the specific class.

We ruled that the damage won't increase until he is a 5th lvl cleric since its a cleric spell.

If there's an official ruling for this its eluding me and I apologize!  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cantrips increase by *character* level, not by class levels.

Your ruling is incorrect.

The wording on the spells is "When you reach X level" not "When your caster level is X" or "When you are a level X class."

Comment: Yep, I was misremembering the conclusion of the duplicate of this question. (I've VTC'd as duplicate, BTW.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks, couldn't remember if we had an actual dupe or just the elf cantrip one.